# How to disable a button to avoid multiple submission?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById('confirm_save').onclick = function() {  
    this.disabled = true;
}
```

I have used the above code but still the button is not disabled

Comment: Please share the HTML part

Comment: Your JavaScript code seems fine. But if you don't provide the HTML, we can't help you solve your issue. We need to know what kind of HTML element `confirm_save` is.

Comment: <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="confirm_save">Confirm</button>

Comment: The code works fine.
I put the code in a wrong function in the first place.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS code is valid but you need to add `type="button"` to your button so it will not act as a submit button and refresh the page returning to the initial status.

```js
document.getElementById('confirm_save').onclick = function() {
  this.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="confirm_save">Confirm save</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
document.getElementById('confirm_save').disabled = true;
```

Comment: In the event handler in OP's code, `this` would be a reference to the events currentTarget. So, the clicked button. Your code is equivalent to OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a variable at the start associated with the button and disable it as such:

```
let btn = document.getElementById("confirm_save");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  btn.disabled = true;
});
```

Hope this helps;

Comment: In the event handler in OP's code, `this` would be a reference to the events currentTarget. So, the clicked button. You're changing the same property on the same element. You're just using a different reference to the element.